# Insect Glaive Upgrading and Progression

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I am new to the Monster Hunter series and have started off using the Insect Glaive weapon as my weapon of choice. However when I have gone to upgrade the weapon there is a ton of information involving feeding the kinsect as well as levelling the weapon.

From what I have learned so far it seems that building speed into the weapon is the best way to build the weapon up, how do I do this, also what is the best way to distribute the elemental damage on the weapon?

Also is cutting or blunt insect better for damage etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elemental damage on your Kinsect is largely negligible, as your main source of damage is the glaive itself rather than the Kinsect. Due to this, choosing between a cutting or blunt Kinsect is also not really important, although some would lean towards a blunt Kinsect giving that you may be targeting the head a lot for red extracts.

Speed+ and Speed++ Nectars are important for increasing the Speed stat of your Kinsect. Speed+ Nectar can be gathered in the wild from plant resource nodes, although they have a relatively low drop rate, as well as purchased from the Wycoon. Speed++ Nectars can be found in abundance in G-rank expeditions, typically at plant resource points inside treasure areas.

Speed+ Nectar boosts Speed at the cost of Stamina. Thus, you'll typically want to use these Nectars before using any Stamina Nectars. Speed++, on the hand, boosts Speed and subtracts a point from all Element stats. If you are intent on using Element Nectars to get an elemental Kinsect, you'll want to use Speed++ Nectar before working on the Element stat.

Comment: for different glaives do I need to level the kinsect all over again?

Comment: Yes, each Glaive has its own Kinsect.

Comment: @Yuuki However the kinsect can evolve and change during upgrades.